# SIGKILL on WSL2

Tags: java, ubuntu, process, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sigkill

I'm running some firebase emulators (firestore, cloud functions) WSL2. For some operations (heavier ones I think) I often  get: `received signal: SIGKILL`. I know it most likely has to do with running out of memory but with 16GB RAM I'm unsure how that happens.

**Environment specs:**

- **16 RAM on 1.5 year old Windows 11 machine**
- **Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL2**
- **Java SDK:**
- openjdk 11.0.17 2022-10-18
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu222.04)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu222.04, mixed mode, sharing)
- **WSL2:**
- Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
- WSLg version: 1.0.51
- MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
- Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
- DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
  Windows version: 10.0.22621.1555

WSL2, Ubuntu and java SDK are all fairly new installs or have been updated recently.

I have tried increasing and decreasing the max RAM usage of WSL2 but neither fixed the issue.

Any ideas how I can prevent the kill signal?
Could it be related to the java SDK?